# Cannot install any packages with yarn add

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

In my react application, I recently switched package managers from `npm` to `yarn`. I'm trying to install some redux packages but they all fail. Commands like `yarn add redux` and `yarn add react-redux` all give me errors like

```
yarn add v1.22.19
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
error Couldn't find package "react-redux" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

. The output of `yarn config list` is

```
yarn config v1.22.19
info yarn config
{
  'version-tag-prefix': 'v',
  'version-git-tag': true,
  'version-commit-hooks': true,
  'version-git-sign': false,
  'version-git-message': 'v%s',
  'init-version': '1.0.0',
  'init-license': 'MIT',
  'save-prefix': '^',
  'bin-links': true,
  'ignore-scripts': false,
  'ignore-optional': false,
  registry: 'https://registry.yarnpkg.com',
  'strict-ssl': false,
  'user-agent': 'yarn/1.22.19 npm/? node/v16.17.1 darwin arm64',
  lastUpdateCheck: 1690739349194
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my yarn setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why yarn could not add any packages is because my `npm config list` had a custom repository configured. I ran the command `npm config delete registry` to delete the custom repository, reset the registry with `yarn config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` , deleted the yarn cache with `yarn cache clean`.

After restarting my terminal, I was able to download `react-redux` using `yarn add react-redux`.

Comment: After adding a package from jfrog from my teams internal repository I got stuck in the same state and never would've gotten out without this, thanks for posting!